# Заполнение двух combobox из одного файла

Tags: c#, winforms

Добрый день.
Помогите понять, как заполнить combobox с условием.
Есть список авторов книг.
Пушкин, Толстой, Грибоедов и так далее. Они помещаются в combobox1.
Есть список произведении у Пушкина 2-3 произведения, у Толстого и так далее. Количество произведении помещается в combobox2.
К примеру в combobox1 я выбираю Пушкина а в combobox2 уже список только его произведении.
И так далее с остальными писателями.
В одном combobox авторы а в другом их книги.
И возможно ли произвести чтение содержимого для combobox 1-2 из одного файла?

Comment: читаете файл и в зависимости что в строке добавляете в 1 или во 2 комбобокс. как отличить что куда - уже зависит как у вас записаны строки в файле

Comment: К примеру можно же форматировать сам исходный файл? Имя писателя после него идут списки произведении.
Пушкин
-Дубровский
-Капитанская дочка
Толстой
-Анна Каренина
-Война и мир.
Вообщем что бы произведения начинались с знака тире.
А сам автор просто с новой строки начинался.
и потом уже в условии считывания помещать в combobox. Или так нельзя?

Comment: можно и так.. можно сделать как в БД..3 колонки:id писателя, id писателя(для книг) и само название.. разделить например |. получается в 1 колонке только айдишника авторов(для книг пустое или прочерк), 2 - айдишники самих авторов которым принадлежит книга

Comment: спасибо. попробую базу данных просто подвязать.

Comment: тогда лучше 2 таблицы создать в бд с авторами и книгами и связать их подобным образом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно обойтись без БД.
Для этого надо создать класс Author, в котором будет имя и фамилия автора, а также все его книги. И класс Book, в котором будет хранится название книги.

**Класс Author**

```
public class Author
{
    private List<Book> books;

    public Author()
    {
        books = new List<Book>();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }


    public void AddBook(Book book)
    {
        books.Add(book);
    }

    public List<Book> GetBooks()
    {
        return books;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1}", Name, Surname);
    }
}
```

**Класс Book**

```
public class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Title;
    }
}
```

После этого надо будет создать List (или любой другой контейнер) с глобальной областью видимости.

При чтении из файла, необходимо будет создать объект класса Author и добавить в него все книги автора (объекты класса Book), после добавить в List, созданный ранее. [authors - List с глобальной областью видимости, в котором хранятся все авторы+их книги]

**Пример**

```
Author a1 = new Author { Name = "A.", Surname = "Пушкин" };
a1.AddBook(new Book { Title = "Руслан и Людмила" });
a1.AddBook(new Book { Title = "Евгений Онегин" });
authors.Add(a1);
```

К combobox1 добавить событие SelectedIndexChanged, в котором будет происходить получение индекса из combobox1 и вывод всех книг автора в combobox2.

**Код для события SelectedIndexChanged**

```
int index = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
if (index < 0 && index >= authors.Count) return;  //проверка, чтобы индекс не находился за границами массива
comboBox2.Items.Clear();      //очистка combobox2, чтобы не было книг других авторов

foreach(Book b in authors[index].GetBooks())
{
    comboBox2.Items.Add(b);
}
```